# Manage sub links in sidebar

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I have a left sidebar which includes links and sub links. It looks as follows -
[image]

when I hover mouse on links sub link display inside of the sidebar(In image I have hovered mouse of posts links and its sub links are displaying inside the sidebar).
Now my question is or what I want is sub links should be displayed outside of sidebar(at right side of sidebar).
Here is what I tried so far

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 90%;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*background-color: #111;*/
    background:#23282D;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin-top:62px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top:50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" id='sidebar_close'>&times;</a>
  <ul style='list-style:none;'>
  <li class='myclass'><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
 <li class='post_list'> <a href="#">Posts</a>
    <ul style='list-style:none;' class='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Add</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Category</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
  <li class='post_list'>
  <a href="#">Pages</a>
<ul style='list-style:none;' class='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Add</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class='media_upload'>Media</a></li>
<li class='post_list'> <a href="#">User</a>
    <ul style='list-style:none;' class='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Add</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
  <li><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please Help me to manage sub links.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your code so it represents the image you are showing. As it is now (https://jsfiddle.net/eystq4t3/) there is nothing

Comment: I have uploaded all code to create sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use position to achieve this 
set li (**.post_list**) to `position:relative;`
and set submenu (**ul**) to `position:absolute;` 
,and you have to remove `overflowx:hidden;` from **sidenav**

this is the code that you should add:

```
.post_list{

      position: relative;
}

.post_list ul{

    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    background: #23282D;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.post_list:hover ul{

  display: block;
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h2gfg218/)

your code will become like this :

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 90%;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*background-color: #111;*/
    background:#23282D;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin-top:62px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.post_list{
  
      position: relative;
}

.post_list ul{
  
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    background: #23282D;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.post_list:hover ul{
  
  display: block;
}



@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" id='sidebar_close'>&times;</a>
  <ul style='list-style:none;'>
  <li class='myclass'><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
 <li class='post_list'> <a href="#">Posts</a>
    <ul style='list-style:none;' class='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Add</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Category</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
  <li class='post_list'>
  <a href="#">Pages</a>
<ul style='list-style:none;' class='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Add</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class='media_upload'>Media</a></li>
<li class='post_list'> <a href="#">User</a>
    <ul style='list-style:none;' class='sub_links'>
        <li><a href='#'>All</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Add</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
  <li><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

U can try this with adjusting the margin to your need.

check this..http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/10787/

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 50%;  # adjust as per your need  
}
```